# Why does @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite runs in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, automation, testng

I have ThreadLocal variables initialized as a part of @BeforeSuite. But since it is running in a separate thread, the initialized variables are not getting passed on to the @Test. Can someone explain to me the reason behind this behavior? Can we make the @BeforeSuite run as a part of the same thread as other annotated methods?

**Code**

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class SampleTest {

ThreadLocal<String> s = new ThreadLocal<>();

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(){
    System.out.println("beforeSuite");
    s.set("Initialisation value");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@BeforeClass
public void beforeclass(){
    System.out.println("beforeclass");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforetest(){
    System.out.println("beforetest");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforemethod(){
    System.out.println("beforemethod");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterMethod
public void aftermethod(){
    System.out.println("aftermethod");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest(){
    System.out.println("afterTest");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterClass
public void afterclass(){
    System.out.println("afterclass");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite(){
    System.out.println("afterSuite");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@Test
public void testMethod(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("My actual Test");
    System.out.println("Value of threadlocal variable s : "+s.get());
}
```

}

**Code Output**

```
beforeSuite
1

beforetest
11

beforeclass
11

beforemethod
11

11
My actual Test
Value of threadlocal variable s : null

aftermethod
11

afterclass
11

afterTest
11

afterSuite
1  

===============================================
Titan Automation
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

**Testng.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Automation" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Test Cases" thread-count="4">
        <classes>
            <class name="org.example.SampleTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: IMO, `ThreadLocal` causes more problems than it solves. I would never use it in new code. I _might_ use a `static ThreadLocal...` when porting old, single-threaded code that used `static` variables into a multi-threaded system, but that's with strong emphasis on "might." IMO the best strategy when designing multi-threaded code is to make sure that whenever some thing needs to be done, _it does not matter which thread does it._ (Note: that rule of thumb need not apply when the "thing to be done" is, wait for some asynchronous event such as an incoming client connection, etc.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the word of advice. But I would like to understand why two different threads are involved in the above execution?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know. When the question is "Why did the authors of package X (JUnit in this case?) choose to implement Y in this way ...?" it can be hard to get meaningful answers unless one of the actual authors happens to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have different threads being spun off where your other methods are running is because you have enabled the parallelism strategy by choosing `parallel="tests"`.

If you would like all the configuration methods to be run on the same thread, you should disable parallelism by setting `parallel="false"` in your `<suite>` tag.